# When storing impala table as textfile, is it posisble to tell it to save column names in the textfile?

Tags: hdfs, text-files, impala

I have created an impala table as

`create table my_schema.my_table stored as textfile as select ...`

As per the definition the table has data stored in textfiles somewhere in HDFS. Now when i run hdfs command such as:

`hadoop fs -cat path_to_file | head`

I do not see any column names. I suppose impala stores the column names somewhere else, but since i would like to work with these textfiles also outside of impala, it would be great if the files would include the headers.

Is there some option i can set when creating the table to add the headers to the text files? Or do i need to figure out the names by parsing the results of `show create table`?

Comment: not sure why you have to add a header to hdfs file ? Can you not dump the data into a file  using `select * from table` and use it ?

Comment: @KoushikRoy you mean doing that over odbc/jdbc? I'd like to avoid that as it seems to be quite a lot slower in my case than reading the textfile directly from hdfs,

Comment: no, ffrom server itself using impala-shell command. Log into hdfs/impala server using putty. issue `impala-shell -k --ssl -i serverxx.comp.com:port -q 'select * from table' -o output.csv`.

Comment: That's a good point, haven't thought of that. Originally i wanted to avoid creating additional files just to add headers as sometimes it's quite a large partitioned dataset to work with, but this could be a good workaround.

Comment: Pls let me know your outcome so i can mark this as answer